# Azure Storage SAS URL Generation

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

I would like to have the SAS URL generated for temporary access to use during backup. How could I do this with powershell.

( Note : Posting this as I couldn't find a straight pointer on how to, since from PHP background and other pages talks about generating with console applications and using. )

Comment: Is PowerShell a requirement for you? There could be a simpler option than this.

Comment: Yes, I am working on POSH, learning and implementing the ARM deployment needs. Below, I had posted the answer to the approach I took. It works like charm till now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MSDN links https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn140255.aspx details the structure of a SAS Url and the same could be generated with cmdlet New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken

```
$SAStokenURL = New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken -Name $BackupContainerName -Context $context -Permission rwdl -StartTime $now.AddHours(-1) -ExpiryTime $now.AddMonths(1) -FullUri 
write-host $SAStokenURL
```

Where, 
$Context is the Storage context
and -FullUri returns the desired URL.

( I might not be complete or missing something and would glad to know further from experts here )

Comment: Please notice that the correct cmdlet is New-AzStorageContainerSASToken https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstoragecontainersastoken?view=azps-10.4.1

Answer (score 0):

To generate a SAS token for providing temporary access to your Storage account containers/blobs through PowerShell, here are the commands that you can fire up to get things working.

$StartTime - Start time from when you want to the access to be given
$expiryTime - End time till when you want to the access to be given

$sasTokenFullURI = New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken -Name $StorageContainerName -Permission $Permission -StartTime $StartTime -ExpiryTime $expiryTime -Context $context -FullUri

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Priyanka. Above thread, I followed with the answer hoping it helps some newbie like me. But thanks once again.